# Rails instance variables working locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So i have some instance variables being set in my rails 3.1 controller that are simply failing to exist when i try to call them in my views on heroku (they work fine locally).

With a similar other model with a similar data structure and the same instance variables, it works fine - which makes it all the weirder. Also some instance vars are getting through ok - so i'm struggling to find out what is causing this problem.

Here's a quick example

```
class PointsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @point = Point.find(params[:id]) 
    @area = @point.area  
    @zoom = 15
    @ff = 0
    @ff = params[:ff].to_i if params[:ff] and params[:ff].to_i
  end
end
```

In my view, if i put: <%= @point.name %> or <%= @ff %> - they work both on local and heroku environments and the values are returned BUT if i put in:

<%= @zoom %> and <%= @area %> these work locally, but return nothing in the heroku environment. it's just totally random.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You're gonna need to post some example code for anyone to be able to help.  Instance variables in what class (module?) and how referenced in the view - that kind of thing.

Comment: sure thing - have added some example code...

Comment: Whoa!  This could only be something completely messed up with Heroku -- the `@zoom` case is completely independent of anything but ruby and really core Rails, and the fact that some work and some don't suggests some sort of memory corruption.  Haven't used Heroku in a while -- is there a way to reset the instance?  I got nothin' else.  You're right -- it's broken.

Comment: Have you tried the following? (1) `heroku restart`, (2) `logger.debug @zoom`, `heroku logs --tail`, (3) `heroku config:add RACK_ENV=development` and see if you get error messages

Comment: Hi Andrew - 1) yes 2) yes - been running heroku logs --tail - although i cant get detailed logs because changing to config.log_level = :debug in production.rb doesn't do anything (but that's a different problem) - not tried using logger.debug yet. and 3) i tried, but it still isn't happy...

Comment: Ok - it seems it's down to inconsistencies in how rails is run. I was playing with 2 different controller files and naming the not-in-use one points_controller1.rb - which is ignored by webbrick or thin locally. Unfortunately, thin running on heroku saw things differently and picked the file up instead (or as well as - i'm not sure) of the intended points_controller.rb. obviously the points_controller1.rb wasn't setting some variables - such as @zoom. Annoying but at least partially self-inflicted. Thanks for your help.